# When I create multiple actions, they affect each other. How to avoid all this?

Tags: actions

I try to create a second action to my character, but when I create it and set the the first keyframe, I noticed that it affects my first action too...
How can I avoid this?

Here a video https://streamable.com/s0tgwu

Comment: are you sure that you have set a keyframe for all the bones at the beginning of the first action? otherwise the first action will keep the transforms from the second action for these specific bones

Comment: do I have to create a keyframe also for the bones that are not directly animated?

Comment: it's better to create a keyframe (RotLocScale) for all your bones at the beginning of an action so that you are sure that no bone will inherit some keyframes from the action that was played before

Comment: it works now! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have good reason not to do it, it's better to create a keyframe (*Rotation Location Scale*) for all your bones at the beginning of an action so that you are sure that no bone will inherit some keyframes from the action that was played before.